# Download corrupted file when export from google drive file with nsurl connection

Tags: google-drive-api, download, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

When i export any file from google drive on ios native application with nsurlconnection or asihttp request download completed but when i have seen in simulator document folder i got corrupted file in that folder every time after download completion of file i got 60 kb of file whether i download any size file.

Please any one know how we can download files form google drive in iphone document folder?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Drive SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files) provides the ability to fetch file contents without using those libraries.